# Draw a random variable from conditional Weibull

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I would like to estimate the remaining lifetime of a number of objects, which all follow a Weibull distribution. Since every object is already runnning for a given amount of time, we are dealing with the conditional Weibull distribution which is given by `1-(1-F(t+T))/(1-F(T))` where `F` is the Weibull-CDF and `T` is the time that has elapsed until now.
My goal is to draw a random variable for the rest-lifetime of each object.
I defined the functions `pweibull.cond` and `rweibull.cond` for calculating the CDF and drawing a random number from the conditional Weibull distribution respectivley.

```
pweibull.cond <- function(q, shape, scale, elapsed){
  1- (1-pweibull(q=q+elapsed, shape = shape, scale=scale))/(1-pweibull(q=elapsed, shape = shape, scale=scale))
}

rweibull.cond <- function(shape, scale, elapsed){
  s <- sapply(seq(0,500,1), function(x){pweibull.cond(q=x, shape=k, scale = lambda, elapsed=elapsed)})
  r <- runif(1)
  q <- min(which(s>r))
  return(q)
}
```

It works but it is rather slow and not very robust coding, so I was wondering if there is any package or built-in function to deal with the conditional Weibull distribution.

p.s. Not quite sure if this is rather a SO or Cross-Validated question.

Comment: What does *rather slow* mean? 5 mins.? 50 mins.? 5 hrs.? Why is this not *robust coding*? It is off-topic to recommend packages or software on SO. OP is asked to do the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) and ask specific questions after implementation. With the said, look into parallel computing to spread out the 501 iterations across multiple cores.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Great. Give parallel processing a try and come back with any issues. There are many online R tutorials, vignettes, videos, blogs on the subject.